# How to set line spacing/height in a JLabel in Java Swing?

Tags: java, html, swing, jlabel, fonts

I have the following JLabel code:

```
JLabel someJLabel = new JLabel("<html>first line<br>second line</html>");
someJLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 16));
```

What I'd like to do is be able to control the line height/spacing between the two lines.

PS: I've also looked at using paragraphs instead of breaklines, but it's the same thing. And I don't know if you can do that within an html  tag without using css (you can't use css within html code in a JLabel in Java Swing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work, but it's not.  `color: green` works though.

`content.add(new JLabel("<html><p style=\"line-height: 150%;\">hi<br>world</p></html>"));`

I guess line-height doesn't work.  That's how you'd do it if you were to use CSS, so maybe you can't do it that way.  [Here's a nice tool](http://xavvy.com/SwingHTMLPreview/) I found which you can use to test if your HTML will work quickly.

Comment: Ya .. CSS support in Swing is currently pretty lame.  The line-height property is modeled but not rendered.  

Javadoc for CSS shows which CSS properties are supported.
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?javax/swing/text/html/CSS.html

Comment: Is there any way to do this without css? And thank you as well for the link!

Answer (score 3):

Check out the setStyleSheet(...) method of the HTMLEditorKit. I've never used it before but I believe it provides some basic support.

Otherwise you can use a JTextPane to control the line spacing. I think you would use:

```
StyleConstants.setLineSpacing(...);
```

You can then change the foreground/background etc to make the text pane look like a label.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm .. CSS in JLabel seems to work for me, if one sticks to supported properties.  Try `padding` (or `margin`) and `font-size`:

```
someJLabel = new JLabel("<html><body><p style=\"padding:10; font-size:30\">First line</p><p style=\"padding:10; font-size:20\">Second line</p></body></html>");
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of Java supports **<p>** tag and CSS **margin** attribute you can use next solution:

```
new JLabel("<html>first line<p style='margin-top:-5'>second line");
```

P.S. Now it is not required to close html tags.

Comment: Also note: `margin-top:-5px` does not work, but `margin-top:-5` does, for whatever reason...

Comment: I used margin-top: 5

Answer (score 0):

You could try using two labels, and setting the distance between the two, as well as the whitespace, using a LayoutManager. I like GridBoxLayout, myself.

Edit: GridBagLayout. Whoops!

Comment: I have to say this is probably going to be allot more robust then messing with the editor kit.

Comment: This may work if you only have 2 lines, but what if it's multiple lines?

Comment: If it is multiple lines, I would use a Text Pane, with camickr's solution.

Answer (score -2):

Does setting empty border helps, like

```
label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
```

method syntax **BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(int top, int left, int bottom, int right)**