# JLabel Adjustment in Swing

Tags: java, html, swing

I tried following

```
JPanel round1Score = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
JLabel accuracy = new JLabel("<html><div style=\"text-align: center; padding: 10px;\">Accuracy score _____ %</html>");
JLabel repeatibility = new JLabel("<html><div style=\"text-align: center; padding: 10px;\">Repeatibility score _____ %</html>");
JLabel classification = new JLabel("<html><div style=\"text-align: center; padding: 10px;\">You have been clasified as _____</html>");
JLabel tendency = new JLabel("<html><div style=\"text-align: center; padding: 10px;\">You have a tendency to _____</html>");

round1Score.add(accuracy);
round1Score.add(repeatibility);
round1Score.add(classification);
round1Score.add(tendency);
```

I get this

[image]

But I want spacing between the Labels like 10px or something like this. What Layout / HTML would you suggest ?

Comment: I'd either use a single HTML table in a single `JLabel` or alternately for a collection of controls -  `GroupLayout` as seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21659516/418556).

Comment: BTW - for spacing between the labels, change `new GridLayout(0,1)` to something like `new GridLayout(0,1,10,10)`..

Answer (score 1):

What about using 'br' inside <> yes that what you need to leave a line

Maybe the answer you need [How to set line spacing/height in a JLabel in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113386/how-to-set-line-spacing-height-in-a-jlabel-in-java-swing)

Take a look here to see how HTML and Java works [as one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html)